# SQL: Need an aggregated pivot view over multiple fields with boolean values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot-table

**Given:**
I have a source table that contains different attributes of footwear in multiple boolean fields and the value indicates whether the footwear of that attribute is available or not. 1=available, 0=not_available.  Sample data is like the following -

| Prod_id | s_7 | s_8 | s_9 | s_10 | c_white | c_black | c_blue | c_brown | c_other | t_shoes | t_sandals | t_slippers | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 002 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 003 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 004 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| 005 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 006 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 007 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 008 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 009 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

There are some more attribute column such as o_casual, o_formal, o_ethnic, m_canvas, m_leather, m_silicon, p_plain, p_textured, p_funky, etc. and all has binary values for respective prod_id. There are more than 50k prod_ids.

**Ask:**
I need a pivoted distribution of the availability for each pair of attributes, and the cell value should indicate the count of prod_ids of the given pair at the intersection.
For example, the count of prod_id with attributes "s_8" and "c_black" is 4 (where s_8=1 and c_black=1). It should be shown in following view, which is useful for further analysis.

| Attribute | s_7 | s_8 | s_9 | s_10 | c_white | c_black | c_blue | c_brown | c_other | t_shoes | t_sandals | t_slippers | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s_7 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| s_8 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| s_9 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | ... |
| s_10 | 0 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| c_white | 2 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| c_black | 1 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| c_blue | 3 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| c_brown | 0 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| c_other | 1 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| t_shoes | 0 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| t_sandals | 1 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| t_slippers | 2 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

It is intuitive that the output table is mirrored across diagonal, and the diagonal cells would contain the total count of prod_id of that particular attribute.

I am new to SQL. Please help me with a logic by which I can achieve desired pivot view. Please note that data is large, so think of a **scalable solution**. Let me know if the problem is not clear and you need some explanation to clarify.

Comment: Consider having a 2-column table: prod_id and a bitstring stored in a `BIGINT`.  Then use suitable boolean operations to check each prod.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query along the lines of -

```sql
SELECT
    's_7' `attribute`,
    SUM(`s_7` = 1) `s_7`,
    SUM(`s_8` = 1) `s_8`,
    SUM(`s_9` = 1) `s_9`,
    SUM(`s_10` = 1) `s_10`,
    SUM(`c_white` = 1) `c_white`,
    SUM(`c_black` = 1) `c_black`,
    SUM(`c_blue` = 1) `c_blue`,
    SUM(`c_brown` = 1) `c_brown`,
    SUM(`c_other` = 1) `c_other`,
    SUM(`t_shoes` = 1) `t_shoes`,
    SUM(`t_sandals` = 1) `t_sandals`,
    SUM(`t_slippers` = 1) `t_slippers`
FROM t1 WHERE `s_7` = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    's_8' `attribute`,
    SUM(`s_7` = 1) `s_7`,
    SUM(`s_8` = 1) `s_8`,
    SUM(`s_9` = 1) `s_9`,
    SUM(`s_10` = 1) `s_10`,
    SUM(`c_white` = 1) `c_white`,
    SUM(`c_black` = 1) `c_black`,
    SUM(`c_blue` = 1) `c_blue`,
    SUM(`c_brown` = 1) `c_brown`,
    SUM(`c_other` = 1) `c_other`,
    SUM(`t_shoes` = 1) `t_shoes`,
    SUM(`t_sandals` = 1) `t_sandals`,
    SUM(`t_slippers` = 1) `t_slippers`
FROM t1 WHERE `s_8` = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    's_9' `attribute`,
...
```

which could be easily built up in your language of choice. Here is a simple example using PHP -

```php
<?php

$attributes = ['s_7', 's_8', 's_9', 's_10', 'c_white', 'c_black', 'c_blue', 'c_brown', 'c_other', 't_shoes', 't_sandals', 't_slippers'];
$sql = null;
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($sql) {
        $sql .= ' UNION ALL ';
    }
    $sql .= "SELECT '$attribute' `attribute`";
    foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
        $sql .= ", SUM(`$attr` = 1) `$attr`";
    }
    $sql .= " FROM t1 WHERE `$attribute` = 1";
}
 echo $sql;
```